# How do I replace part of a string using regex

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to clean up a mongo db dump. I want to replace all the '\"'  in strings where an alphanumeric character is followed by '\"' with spaces. This is what I have so far
`sed   -e 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]\\"/ /g' a.txt`

The problem is, this sed replaces not just '\"', but the one character immediately preceding it. So 'mystring\"' becomes 'mystrin '. I wanted the output 'mystring '

Comment: edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a capturing group in the regex pattern and the `\1` placeholder in the replacement part that would restore the alphanumeric char:

```
sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\)\\"/\1 /g' a.txt
          ^^           ^^    ^^
```

You may replace `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `[[:alnum:]]` to make the regex a bit more idiomatic (`[:alnum:]` matches any alphanumeric chars).

[Online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/x92D75):

```
s='mystring\"'
sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\)\\"/\1 /g' <<< "$s"
# => mystring
sed -e 's/\([[:alnum:]]\)\\"/\1 /g' <<< "$s"
# => mystring
```